# Regularity of $|x|^{1+\alpha(x)}$ for $0<\alpha(x)<1$

Tags: real-analysis

If the function $\alpha:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth enough, say $C^\infty$ and satisfies $0<\alpha(x)<1$ for every $x$, then is it true that at each point $x_0$, $|x|^{1+\alpha(x)}$ is $C^{(1,\alpha(x_0))}$? How much regularity to I need from $\alpha$?

I should clarify what I mean with $u\in C^{1,\beta}$ at a point $x$: I mean that there exists an affine function $l_x(y)=a_x+b_x\cdot y$ such that for every $0<r<1$
\begin{align*}
\sup_{y\in B_r(x)}|u(y)-l_x(y)|\leq C_x r^{1+\beta}.
\end{align*}

Comment: No. If $\alpha =1$ (this is smooth, of course), then the function is not smooth at the origin. 

You can take the derivative of $|x|$ (use $|x|^2 =\langle x,x \rangle$ and solve for the derivative of $|x|$) and apply the chain rule to analyze the behavior.

Comment: What does $C^{1,\alpha}$ mean if $\alpha < 0$ or $>1$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to bound the exponent. I edited the question.

Comment: $|x|^{\alpha(x)} = \exp(\alpha(x) \log|x|)$ may help :)

Comment: Then just consider $\alpha \equiv 1/2$? I think you should think again if you want a positive answer

Comment: Okay, should be fixed now. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the patience :)